# Postgresql ILIKE/LIKE ANY returns no results when using a pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table (foods) in a PostgreSQL db (version 12.1) that has a column called common_names, which is a Text Array (TEXT[]). In the data, the term "family style" appears 35 times in a common_names entry in the database.

The following 3 queries all return the value '35':

`select count(1) from foods where 'family style' = ANY (common_names);`

`select count(1) from foods where 'family style' LIKE ANY (common_names);`

`select count(1) from foods where 'FAMILY STYLE' ILIKE ANY (common_names);`

All of the following queries return zero (0):

`select count(1) from foods where '%family%' LIKE ANY (common_names);`

`select count(1) from foods where '%family%' ILIKE ANY (common_names);`

`select count(1) from foods where 'family%' LIKE ANY (common_names);`

`select count(1) from foods where 'FAMILY%' ILIKE ANY (common_names);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `... where exists (select 1 from unnest(common_names) as x where x ilike '%family%')`

Comment: Unrelated, but `count(1)` is actually (slightly) slower than `count(*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this all in the `WHERE` clause:

```
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(common_names) u(common_name)
              where u.common_name like '%family%'
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern(s) goes on the right hand side of the `LIKE`, just like it would if there were no `ANY`.  The thing on the left hand side is just a string, not a pattern.

The below yields false:

```
SELECT '%family%' LIKE 'family style'
```

Wrapping the RHS in `ANY(ARRAY[...])` isn't going to change the meaning.

Comment: I don't think so; the ANY is used to match any item in the array. Plus, the first three commands use this format and they work. The documentation example is this:

`SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);`

here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/arrays.html

Comment: I think you missed his point.  The wildcard goes after the like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of one my colleagues, we were able to figure this out.

So, for starters, it doesn't look like you can use LIKE or ILIKE with array columns - you can, it just doesn't work correctly. It appears like only exact matches can be used.

However, you can **unnest** arrays for search purposes.

Here's the query that finally worked:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT global_id, common_names FROM foods,
        LATERAL unnest(common_names) AS common_names(common_name)
    WHERE common_name LIKE '%family%'
    GROUP BY global_id, common_names) AS X;
```